# Django Concatenate an object list using tags

Tags: python, django

I have some variables in one template :

```
<p> {{ area.description }} {{area.boss}} {{area.dept}}
```

and I need to concatenate them and count the characters to set a number where the string will cut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved: in my model I defined this:

```
  def get_full_information (self): return '%s %s %s' (self.description, self.boss, self.dept)
```

And in the template:

```
{{ area.details.get_full_information|truncatechars:30 }}
```

This way I got truncated the chars in the number of characters I needed to

Answer (score 3):

how to concat

```
{{ area.description|add:area.boss|add:area.dept }}
```

how to count all chars

```
{{ area.description|add:area.boss|add:area.dept|length }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I resolved:
in my model I defined this: 


        `def get_full_information (self):
        return '%s %s %s' (self.description, self.boss, self.dept)`



And in the template:


 `{{ area.details.get_full_information|truncatechars:30 }}`


This way I got truncated the chars in the number of characters I needed to